# Strategy Design Pattern for handling requests

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I need to refactor class, which handles requests. I don't need chain of responsibility, because in compile time I have specified which request is connected to which handler.

My idea is to create one singleton class which is responsible for all logic. 
For example it will have pointer to database object and it will handle requests.

There will be interface for HandlerMessage and many class derived from them.

Suppose we have:

```
class Singleton {
    Database db;
    int handleMessage(const Request& in, Response& out);
};

int Singleton::handleMessage(const Request& in, Response& out) {
    int result = 0;
    HandlerMessage* handler;
    if(in.type == RequestType::A)
        handler = new HandlerA();
    else if(in.type == RequestType::B)
        handler = new HandlerB();
    else
        return -1;
    result = handler->handle(in, out);
    delete handler;
    return result;
}
```

However HandlerMessage needs to use Database and I wonder how to get use them.
I can pass pointer to database as an argument of handle function in HandlerMessage class.
However it seems to me strange, because all time I will pass the same argument. Moreover not all handlers needs to use database.

My question is:

```
class MessageHandler {
    static Database* db;
}
```

this a good solutions, where I initialized db from MessageHandler class with db from SingeltonClass in Singleton constructor?

Or it is better to use more sophisticated solutions?

Thank You for any reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the reference to the database in the constructor of the handler like this:

```
handler = new HandlerA(db); //HandlerA needs to deal with database
handler = new HanlderB();   //HandlerB doesn't need to deal with database
```

`HandlerA` can look like this:

```
class HandlerA : public MessageHandler
{
    HandlerA(Database& db) { /* ... */ }

    int handle(const Request& in, Response& out) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: You are right, but I would prefer to hide such things in Singleton class. I would prefer to treat all handlers equal, they should decide if they want to use db or not.

Comment: Then they must have the same access to the database and you can provide that since you've got your Singleton class. Or, as you said, you could pass the reference to database as a parameter of `handle`.

Comment: Ok, Thank You! It also seems to me that in such static example polymorphism is not essential. Static variable seems to be enough.